# Place figures after the cross-reference

Tags: floats, hyperref, cross-referencing

Is there a way to make sure figures and tables appear **after** the cross reference?
I'm 100% sure I have read that a package has got the option to do exactly that, but I can't recall for the life of me what the name of it is. Can someone here help?
I know I could just use some float-controller like [H] but I don't want to do that to my 50+ figures.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside,openright,hidelinks]{memoir}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage[%
    bindingoffset=0.5in,%
    left=1in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1.5in,%
    footskip=.5in,%
    marginparwidth=2.2cm,
    ]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\subsection{heading A}

\lipsum[1] \cref{fig:label1,fig:label2}.  

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{frog.jpg}
    \caption{this figure should be after the first crossreference, but it isnt.}
    \label{fig:label1}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{frog.jpg}
    \caption{this figure is correctly placed }
    \label{fig:label2}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: `flafter` package (part of the core base release)

Comment: Thanks for the ultrafast answer. Though this is the package I remember, and it does what's advertised, it also overdoes it. Now all my figures are closer together than people in a queue in walmart. I think I'll do the floats anyway.

Comment: If your figures are being pushed to the top of the next page instead the bottom of this page, try `\def\bottomfraction{0.7}`.